# Process migration in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process

Is it possible to migrate/inject (into) another process memory space using python? I am new to python I know it's possible in c is there any working method or documentation on process migration in python?

Comment: Please present your use-case and what you have tried so far! I suspect an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have been trying to recreate the poorman's migration technique!

I am stuck but so far I have wrote it till here

```
import ctypes
import psutil

pid = 5976

kernel32 = cdll.kernel32
hProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess(0x0020, 0, pid)
print(kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, ctypes.c_void_p() , 1024, "MEM_COMMIT", "PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE"))
```